# Display logfile before committing transaction. Only commit if user confirms

Tags: php, jquery, logging, transactions, commit

When I update records in the data I want to show the user the update log BEFORE the transaction is committed and give the option to continue or roll back.

The code that commits the updates to the database follows this format:-

```
<?php
include 'submitLogger.php';

// Begin logging
ini_set( "error_log", $logFile );
ini_set( "log_errors", "On" );
ini_set( "display_errors", "Off" );
error_log( "Log file '" . $logFile . "' created" );

// Open the database
.
.

error_log( "Connect OK" );
.
.

error_log( "Transaction started (autocommit OFF)\n" ); 
.
.

error_log( "Processing " . count( $deletes ) . " item(s) marked for deletion..." ); 
.
.


// commit changes
error_log( "Committing changes..." ); 
if ( mysqli_commit( $link ) === false ) {
  mysqli_rollback( $link );
  error_log( "Commit failed. Transaction rolled back." ); 
  $response['error'] = "Could not commit changes. Transaction rolled back.";
} else {
  error_log( "Commit successful!" ); 
  $response['success'] = "Success!";
}

// close DB connection
.
.

// Return result
.
.
```

This is the code that loads the update code above and then displays the logfile, but AFTER the transaction has been committed:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {


  // send AJAX request to perform the updates and begin logging
  $.post(
    '../lib/updateMenu.php', 
    sendData,
    function( response ) {
      // was it successful?
      if ( typeof response.success === 'undefined' ) {
        // no - show alert
        if ( response.error ) {
          alert( response.error );
        }
        console.error( "Amend not successful" );
        console.error( response );
        return;
      }

      // delete the AmendmenuAmendselected program window to force a reload on next click
      $( "#programWindowAmendmenuAmendselected" ).remove();
    },
    "json"
  ).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( 'Unexpected error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown );
    console.error( 'Unexpected error during amend: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown );
    console.error(jqXHR);
  }).complete(function() {
    // once a reply is received, stop the logging
    ajaxLogtail.stopTail();      
  });

  // begin querying log file
  var ajaxLogtail = new AjaxLogtail( '../lib/ajaxLogtail.php?logfile=' + logFile, "programWindowAmendmenuSubmit" );  
  ajaxLogtail.startTail();
});

</script>
```

I cannot figure out how to split this so that I can display the logfile and then, if there weren't any update errors, commit the transaction.

Does anyone have a neat idea to help, please?

Comment: admin/moderator please close or delete this question as there doesn't appear to be a reasonable solution

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know you cannot do it.
At least not with php.
Php is a server side, script code runned.
It runs from the first line to the last line, stop.

You however can run a select and tell how many records will be at example deleted, give those data to the ajax and then on confirm do the real delete operation (and commit the change).

However you can (if your web app is used by a lot of people) have a situation where your ajax find 25 element to be deleted and the real delete query will delete 26 or more. For that better re-think your logic a little and produce a log after the delete query.

Comment: Correct Marco, there doesn't appear to be a simple solution. The updates won't be many as only administrators will use this functionality, but still, your point is valid, the actual update may end up being different to the log.

Comment: And please note that you cannot stop (in php) a transaction, it will end up in rollback if not committed, the transaction states aren't like other languages (that will have other troubles).

Comment: I suspect I will have to create some html containing a javascript prompt in my php code that will display the log and ask the user if they want to continue. Probably after the "error_log( "Committing changes..." );" statement. I'm just not sure how to get the response back from the user. Any ideas Marco?

Comment: You can create two Ajax functions. The first one ask a select of the "selected" element, so is a proto-delete, it will tell the Administrator How many rows will be deleted. In this page a Button will allow the real delete.

Comment: OtherWise you can delete only by id, you can create an array with id of elements and pass it with ajax to do a delete (delete from table where id = $myvar) for each array element, it will be more secure.

Comment: I like your first idea Marco. (I'm already doing your second idea.) I can run the transactgion twice, roll it back the first time, display the log, ask user if that's what they want to do. If yes, then run the transaction again (without log) and commit it. I will have to analyse what the risk is that the second transaction does exactly what the first one does, but I think it will.

Comment: I don't like it because it's very messy. Any other ideas Marco (or anyone else)?

Comment: The first idea is the probably most used for mass operations. I do not think there are that many possibility.